# Compiling 32bit on 64bit machine : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<someLibs>

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc, g++

i'm currently trying to compile some code as 32bit on a 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 machine. If i compile the code with the normal make command it all works fine.

Now, in order to compile it as 32bit i added the -m32 option to the C- & CXXFLAGS. Works fine until i get some errors about missing librarys like `-lGL`, `-lGLU`, `-lX11`, `-lXext`, `-lpng`. Okay, the first lib (`-lGL`) I found in `/usr/lib32/nvidia-304` which i added via the `-L` option. 
The other libs are all found in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` but adding that via `-L` does not solve a thing.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Here is the full gcc-command leading to the error

```
gcc myprog.o -m32 (...) -lX11 -lXext -lpng -lm -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lGL -L/usr/lib32/nvidia-304 -lpthread -o myprog
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
```

Another thing: In the `/usr/lib32/nvidia-304` i found a `libGL.so` PLUS an `libGL.la` while in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` I only can find `.so` files.

Comment: Just for clarification, there is a `libpng.so` in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` ?

Comment: Yes, `./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so.3` exists.

Comment: Hm, seems like @lolando might be on the right track then. You need a `libpng.so`, which may be a symlink to `libpng.so.3`. Did you install the 32bit libs the official, Ubuntu-supported way?

Comment: Hi, creating symbolic links like `libpng.so` to `libpng.so.3` truly worked. I dont have root access to the system so i dont know how it got installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but i had some time ago a similar problem where some symbolic links were missing under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. Perhaps you are facing a similar issue?

Comment: Hi, as mentioned in the post above the creation of symbolic links worked so far. Thanks!